# How to use allegro5 in a cmake project?

Tags: cmake, allegro5

I'm trying to include allegro5 in a cmake project.

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_executable(app main.c)

pkg_check_modules(allegro-5 REQUIRED allegro-5)
target_link_libraries(app ${ALLEGRO5_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(app PUBLIC ${ALLEGRO5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

My main.c is:

```
#include <allegro5/system.h>

int main()
{
    al_init();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run `cmake --build .` I get the following error:

```
main.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `al_install_system'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm looking for an example CMakeLists.txt file of an application that links with allegro5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it except for a misunderstanding of [`pkg_check_modules()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html).

The first argument to `pkg_check_modules()` is a literal prefix that you choose. This will be the prefix to all the variables that `pkg_check_modules()` sets. If you had chosen "foo", the variables that would have been set would be `foo_LIBRARIES`, `foo_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `foo_CFLAGS`, etc.

You chose the prefix "allegro-5", but in subsequent commands you're trying to use the varibales `ALLEGRO_LIBRARIES` and `ALLEGRO5_INCLUDE_DIRS`. These variables aren't set, because the variables that you actually want are `allegro-5_LIBRARIES` and `allegro-5_INCLUDE_DIRS`. Change those 3 three commands to:

```
pkg_check_modules(ALLEGRO5 REQUIRED allegro-5)
target_link_libraries(app ${ALLEGRO5_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(app PUBLIC ${ALLEGRO5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

or:

```
pkg_check_modules(allegro-5 REQUIRED allegro-5)
target_link_libraries(app ${allegro-5_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(app PUBLIC ${allegro-5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Once you have the prefix given in `pkg_check_modules()` matching the variables you want to use, your project will build correctly. (Assuming of course, Allegro 5 is installed correctly.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation!